# CSS scale transition issue on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, transform, css-transitions

I am working on a CSS scale transition and I've found some issues on Firefox (Mac). In short I have 2 `divs`, the former scales down and fades out:

```
@-webkit-keyframes scaleDownTo {
  to { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: scale(.8); }
}
@-moz-keyframes scaleDownTo {
  to { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: scale(.8); }
}
@keyframes scaleDownTo {
  to { opacity: 0; transform: scale(.8); }
}
```

The latter scales down and fades in:

```
@-webkit-keyframes scaleDownFrom {
  from { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); }
}
@-moz-keyframes scaleDownFrom {
  from { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: scale(1.5); }
}
@keyframes scaleDownFrom {
  from { opacity: 0; transform: scale(1.5); }
}
```

The issue is on the appearing `div`: during the transition, when it comes out, the size does not cover the parent `div` and its position is anchored at the top left corner. When the transition ends up, the `div` suddenly gets its original size and position.

Note: I've found this snippet on a Codrops tutorial and I've noticed that it also happens on their demo ([view example](http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/) -> choose the transition called **SCALE DOWN / SCALE DOWN**), so I was wondering if it's just a FF bug or there's a fix for that. Maybe someone can test it on PC+FF and let me know if it does work or not.

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NwNDP/embedded/result/) that I've created. As you can see, the issue happens on Firefox when the container width is > than the image size.

Comment: Please set up a fiddle

Comment: I dont think it is a bug - they just reset to default state - no?

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NwNDP/embedded/result/). As you can see, the issue happens on Firefox when the container width is > than the image size.

Comment: Everything works fine, FF 26 on Mac

Comment: Its working well. But in firefox it will give slow response but working properly.

Comment: For me it just works if browser window is narrow. Can you please check if it works when browser window is wider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more to this than you have demonstrated.

I have recreated (based upon what you have supplied) a carousel using Owl Slider. Firstly this Slider has a few issues which are inherent such as support in IE for transitions - they are not supported in IE - *people be warned*.

Secondly when I use `animation-delay:` in Firefox it breaks the animation, if it is not present the animation works; albeit without the delay - which in this case I can live with. I would say that this is your issue, as it resets the image as you describe and the animation continues after that point.

In your fiddle you have not supplied all the required files, therefore it doesn't even move through all the slides so the whole thing had to be re-created to have an insight into how it works.

Please see my demo for clarification > http://codepen.io/mofeenster/pen/smwAD